# PICASSO Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, picasso

I had this big problem with picasso all the time.
I got like this

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env
   at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
   at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:729)
   at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.(SourceFile:205)
   at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder.build(Picasso.java:864)
   at com.destina.travling.ui.main.fragment.home.restaurant.detail.FoodImageAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FoodImageAdapter.java:58)
   at com.destina.travling.ui.main.fragment.home.restaurant.detail.FoodImageAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FoodImageAdapter.java:27)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.getItemCount(RecyclerView.java:6781)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
   at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3336)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1248)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1593)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
   at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1502)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:556)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1248)
   at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1593)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
   at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
   at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:805)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6085)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:693)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19886)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2323)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1414)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1667)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1302)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6441)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:876)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:688)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:623)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:862)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

I just modified picasso setup like this :

```
OkHttpClient client = HttpsClient.getHttpsClient(context);
        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
                .memoryCache(new LruCache(getBytesForMem()))
                .build();
        picasso.load(link)
                .fit()
                .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
                .into(holder.ivFoodImage);

private int getBytesForMem() {
        ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (activityManager != null) {
            activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
        }

        double availableMemory = memoryInfo.availMem;
        return (int) (12 * availableMemory / 100);
    }
```

And i using piccasso library version of `com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828`

Previously, I put the memoryCache then I got often that error but right now the nightmare has coming again.

And my question is

1. How to make Picasso work great without `OutOfMemoryError`?
2. Can `Picasso.singleton` make this problem clear?

I know, some user maybe recommend to try another library, but i still use library because my API using self signed cert to get API. And that reason why you can see the OkHttp combine with Picasso.

But if you keep trying suggest to move on with another library, maybe you can teach me how to use self signed cert to get API use your recommended Library.

I will give up-vote for any question, thankyou :).

Comment: your code is not complete here, but according to your error, I recommend to create the Picasso object once in your adapter constructor and stop this object recreation on every loop of RecyclerView binding.

Comment: can you give me an example of the code that you mean?

Comment: `I just using standard code of picasso`. WRONG. This is not standard code. You modified the caching and client networking behavior.

Comment: Ow okay, i has been edited. Can you remove the downvote :)

Answer (score 1):

this is a simplified answer to your request in comments but I doubt it works or not for you:

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

List<Object> items;
Picasso picasso;
Context context;
public TestAdapter(List<Object> inputs, Context in_context) {
    items = inputs;
    context = in_context;
    OkHttpClient client = HttpsClient.getHttpsClient(context);
    picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
            .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
            .memoryCache(new LruCache(getBytesForMem()))
            .build();

}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //return your ViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // some codes here

    picasso.load(link)
            .fit()
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
            .into(holder.ivFoodImage);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

private int getBytesForMem() {
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)
            context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (activityManager != null) {
        activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);
    }

    double availableMemory = memoryInfo.availMem;
    return (int) (12 * availableMemory / 100);
}
}
```

in your activity create your RecyclerView adapter using the new constructor.

```
//get your recyclerView from your layout as mRecyclerView
LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(your_data,this);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: can you give me a reason why we should put picasso on public adapter?

Comment: because it is memory efficient and it worked for me for a similar problem.

Comment: and what i do in OnDestroy?

Comment: for what? this object is local in your adapter (make it private). garbage clear will do its work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Picasso** yet solve the famous out of memory error,
The point is you are running out of memory and this could happen with any other library too

Sometimes big size images cause this kind of problem
Sometimes setting large heap in manifest can solve the issue
, ...
There is a huge amount of data in **stackoverflow** on out of memory and **Picasso**

The point is you should take care of the memory and dissect it
I recommend focusing on heap issue instead of changing the library and facing another new problem

Don't forget monitoring heap and utilizing heap functions too

Comment: I has set largeheap but it's not work then every image actually load more than 100KB for thumbnail and cover. It's it the problem?

Comment: Normally 100k is not considered a big image and Mega images can normally cause such a problem but you should consider the allocated heap memory by your device too, BTW I remember I once had a problem with Builder too, Is there any logical reason that you don't simply use the URL of the image in Picasso?

Comment: Hmm maybe resize is the great choice, in my JSON case, if has no image the value is "-" and the value when there is image link without https, so i put the string with http:// + link

Comment: I mean can't you forget Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context) and okhttp and simply utilize Picasso.with(c).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).error(R.drawable.error).into( ... , about URL, sometimes there is no need to put extra data like http or even the name of the site in JSON and you can define them as constant or variable in the Android application

Comment: Like i said, my JSON need cert to access API without that we can't use API same like image